# JTable JCombobox not deselecting

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

If I have a JComboBox within a JTable then it all works great except if you click on the combobox to trigger it's dropdown to appear and then either click on the same location on the combobox again or click on the JPanel.

This leaves the combobox in some weird selected state with it highlighted and the down arrow visible. If you were to actually select a value from the combobox instead then the combobox appeared deselected and the down arrow is not visible.

When in this selected state it not only looks weird but if you attempt to change the table values programmatically the "selected" combobox does not update it's value until you click it again.

Below is an example simply click a combobox and then select a value and see how the table appears and then select a combobox but instead of selecting a value click on the red JPanel and observe how that combobox appears now.

Again when in this state it does not allow dynamic updates. How do I get it so it doesn't get stuck in this selected/highlighted state.

```java
public class JTableTest extends JFrame {

    public JTableTest() {

        String[] columns = {"1", "2", "3"};
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 1);
        JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
        table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
        table.setFocusable(false);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            JComboBox cb = new JComboBox();
            cb.setFocusable(false);
            cb.addItem("a");
            cb.addItem("b");
            cb.addItem("c");
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(cb));
        }
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        jp.setBackground(Color.red);
        jp.add(table);
        
        this.add(jp);
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTableTest jt = new JTableTest();
        jt.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied the code into my IDE and corrected some warnings and made sure that Swing layout managers were used correctly.  I duplicated the problem that the OP discovered.  If you left-click on the column headers, the selection popup closes.  If you left-click anywhere else on the JFrame, the selection popup arrow remains visible.  I tried setting a selection and it didn't make any difference.  The example code didn't allow me to test dynamic updating.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc my swing is a bit rusty - but I think that's related to the ominous terminate-edit-on-focusLost: there is no way to terminate when clicking elsewhere. What is supported (to a certain extent), is force termination when focus is moved to outside of the table. The conditions for that are a) set a client property "terminateEditOnFocusLost" to boolean true and __have__ something to focus (which this example doesn't seem to have).

Comment: @kleopatra if you think what you are proposing may solve the issue can you edit the above example code to show what you mean please

Comment: concededly, my comment might be a bit confusing ;) The main point: the table is in editing state and that editing state is _not terminated_ when clicking elsewhere. So your problem is related to editing, not selecting. The solution is to find a way to _terminate the editing_ on whatever user interaction. That's not trivial in the general case, but might be solvable in a fully controlled context. Good luck!